# How to add property file in Mock method - Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to write JUnit test cases for an application which is in Java Spring Boot 1.2.5.
I have a service class and I am writing JUnit test cases Using Mockito for the same.

**Service Class**

```
class ManualWorkFlowService implements ManualWorkFlowInterface {
              @Autowired
              private Environment environment;

              public void fetchFlowData(Long flowId) {
                            String config = environment.getProperty("manual.workflow.config");
                             // Big method body to follow.
              }
}
```

**JUnit class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LMVendorServiceTest extends BaseTest {

              @InjectMocks
              private ManualWorkFlowInterface service = new ManualWorkFlowService();
 
              @Test
              public void fetchFlowDataTest() throws Exception {
                             service.fetchFlowData("1234");
              }            
}
```

The Junit method calls the fetchFlowData() method, but the `environment.getProperty("manual.workflow.config")` in original method throws null pointer exception (Because environment property is null)

I have fixed the same like below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LMVendorServiceTest extends BaseTest {

              @InjectMocks
              private ManualWorkFlowInterface service = new ManualWorkFlowService();

              @Mock
              private Environment mockenvironment;
 
              @Test
              public void fetchFlowDataTest() throws Exception {
              when(mockenvironment.getProperty("manual.workflow.config")).thenReturn("something");
                             service.fetchFlowData("1234");
              }            
}
```

**My doubts are,**

1. Can I configure the same property file which the original
   application is using in my Test Class? If yes how?
2. Is it possible, when I call the original method (fetchFlowData(Long flowId)) from Junit, it automatically takes the application property files configured in original application so that environment.getProperty("manual.workflow.config") works fine without configuring a property file separately in Test Class?

I have tried the below approach but the @Value is not fetching property file value

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PropertySource("file:C:\\properties\\application.properties")
public class LMVendorServiceTest extends BaseTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ManualWorkFlowInterface service = new ManualWorkFlowService();

    @Mock
    private Environment mockenvironment;
            
    @Value("${manual.workflow.config}")
    private String property;      //Null here
            
    @Test
    public void fetchFlowDataTest() throws Exception {
        when(mockenvironment.getProperty("manual.workflow.config")).thenReturn(property);
         service.fetchFlowData("1234");
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

To:

```
private Environment environment;

@Autowired
void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
    // Doesn't need to be public if your service and test are in the same package
    this.environment = env;
}
```

And use Spring's [`MockEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/env/MockEnvironment.html) in your test, adding a `PropertySource` for whichever properties file you want:

```
MockEnvironment env = new MockEnvironment();

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/my.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
env.getPropertySources().addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("testProperties", props));

ManualWorkFlowInterface service = new ManualWorkFlowService();
service.setEnvironment(env);
```

Comment: Better, use `@Value("${myProperty}")` and make it a constructor argument.